# Not able to get page using http request

Tags: java, android, jsoup

This is the code, which has to load a page and store it in `string[]`. I dont understand the problem as it is not loading the page and it is **throwing no errors**.

If any one knows any **better ways to send a http request then please post it** or please tell me the problem.

```
 //some code    
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                int j=0;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    new MyTask().execute();});     
    //some code

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try {

                            String ssr="";
                            URL n = new URL("http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=nagpur+to+pune");
                            URLConnection nc = null;
                            nc = n.openConnection();
                            BufferedReader in = null;
                            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nc.getInputStream()));
                            String inputLine;
                            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                ssr+=inputLine;
                            }

                            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(ssr);
                            Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("dir-mrgnr");
                            String str = el.text();
                            str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+[.] ", "\n");
                            string = str.split("\n");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "in Background",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        speakOut("not Working");
                        //speakOut("work in progress");
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        super.onPostExecute(result);

                    }

                }
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is just a typo, but what is `yahoo.openConnection()`? It should be `n.openConnection()`.

Comment: no that was not the problem... the new code is not working.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to download the page and parse it then.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // Better than an array

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=nagpur+to+pune").get(); // Connect to url and parse its conntent
Elements el = doc.select("*.dir-mrgnr"); // Every tag with 'dir-mrgnr' class - or use getElementsByClass() as you did

for( Element element : el )
{
    list.add(element.text());
}
```

Btw. **dont** use [`+=` on a String in a loop](http://www.venishjoe.net/2009/11/java-string-concatenation-and.html); use a `StringBuilder` instdead!